# Duplicated /blog link at pagination section

Tags: octopress

I new to octopress and I passed thought an issue with main page links.
All links was duplicated like /blog/blog and I fixed this at source files.

Now, everything is fine but "Blog Archives" link (/blog/blog/archives) at div with class "pagination", at index.html, close to footer section.
I looked into source files and it appears fine but if I run "rake generate", after change the wrong url at index.html, it backs to /blog/blog/archives.

Which file I need to change to fix that issue?

The header "Blog Archives" is fine.

Comment: How do you fixed that in source files? I have the same duplicated issue.

Comment: I solved changing permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/ for permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title/ in _config.yml

Comment: I made the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved changing permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/ for permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title/ in _config.yml, like hsigrist said in the comment.